# Gitlab CI removes user attachments and uploaded files

Tags: git, continuous-integration, pipeline, gitlab-ci

I am using **Git** and **Gitlab**.
Using **Gitlab CI pipelines** (`.gitlab-ci.yml` file) I am trying to deploy my project to a shared host.

It works fine, but when pipeline runs, it removes user attachments, profile pictures, documents and all files that users upload directly to host and those files don't exist in git master branch.
What should I do to make Gitlab ignore my `uploads` folder and all sub-folders in pipelines?

Here we have `.gitignore` file:

```
.idea
files/
```

And this one is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
deploy:
  script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
  - lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u "USER","PASSWORD" "HOST"; mirror -Rnev ./ ./public_html --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/"
  only:
  - master
```

Comment: What do u mean remove? doe not upload them or deleting them

Comment: @CodeWizard I don't have those files in my local computer or in git repository. Each user uploads some files to the host (like profile pictures). But git deletes these files because it doesn't find those files in repository (syncs uploaded files in the host with repository)

Comment: I miss the point, the user uploads those files, they are not in git so what do u expect to happen?

Comment: @CodeWizard Git deletes those files from the host. I want git to let them be there.

Comment: What is the output of your git status before the command? do you see those folders?

Comment: @CodeWizard No I don't. Everything is fine with pushing, the problem is in **CI** that deletes files in **uploads** folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184175/discussion-between-mahyar-khanbabai-and-codewizard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Git and everything to do with your `lftp` command.  When you're uploading data with `lftp`, you're using the `-e` (`--delete`) option to `mirror`, which the man page specifies as “delete files not present at the source”.  Since your upload files aren't present on the source, they're deleted.

If you want to continue to use this option, you need to move your uploads folder out of the same root and into a separate directory; otherwise, you should stop using this option.